# Dictionary items not working when passed through powershell command

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, dictionary, backslash

I have a dictionary created from a .txt file that contains desktop links. I need these links to be plugged in to a powershell command. However when I use `'%s' % my_data[key]` I get extra backslashes and therefore powershell will not process the command because it has no idea what to look for, how do I remove extra backslashes?

```
['powershell.exe', "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell\n$sh.CreateShortcut('C:\\Users\\johns\\desktop\\python\\Survey+Update\\testing this shared.lnk\n').TargetPath"]
```

Comment: That dictionary you pasted there is a variable in your Python code, right?

Comment: Yes because when I run it that is what appears.
the full command  looks like this.

([r"powershell.exe", "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell" + "\n" + "$sh.CreateShortcut('%s').TargetPath" % (my_data[key])])

Comment: On it, give me a minute

Comment: How are you sending this to powershell?

Comment: subprocess.Popen([r"powershell.exe", "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell" + "\n" +  "$sh.CreateShortcut(%s).TargetPath" % my_data[key]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

Comment: I tried something out, not sure if it works because I have no Windows machine to test it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the double backslash was not the problem. for my code `subprocess.Popen([r"powershell.exe", r"$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell" + "\n" + "$sh.CreateShortcut(%s).TargetPath" % my_data[key]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`.

The dictionary had \n at the end of each line. I used `my_dict[key].replace("\n","")` to get rid of it. also the path needed "path" `\"%s\"` fixed that. I don't know how powershell was able to handle the double backslash???? but it did

Answer (score 0):

Try using os.path.normpath as such:

```
dir_file = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/johns/desktop/python/Survey+Update/testing this shared.lnk")
['powershell.exe', "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell\n$sh.CreateShortcut({0}).TargetPath".format(dir_file)]
```

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: Dang it, let me keep trying

Comment: Oh and incase I did not say it enough. Thank you for taking the time. I looked for 2 days before posting.

Comment: @JohnShiveley I changed my answer, see how it goes now. And you're welcome, hope I can fix this one.

Comment: upon second look I see that this is a different method all together. I am using a dictionary because I pulled these paths from a text file. I need each item in my dictionary to run through this powershell script.
' for key, value in my_data.iteritems():
 subprocess.Popen([r"powershell.exe", "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell" + "\n" +  "$sh.CreateShortcut(%s).TargetPath" % my_data[key]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] '

Comment: @JohnShiveley That's alright. I'll be honest, if that one doesn't work I have no clue what else to try.

Comment: That's okay thanks for your help. `I can do this now XD`

Comment: If you have a chance please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062041/python-capture-reply-from-powershell?noredirect=1#comment59771264_36062041