# Python Capture reply from powershell

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, stringio, cstringio

The code below works when typed manually however when I run the program.py nothing prints. My ultimate goal is to retrieve this data from user pc to create an easy way to recreate shortcuts.... My users somehow lose them lol

```
import smtplib, os, subprocess, sys
from string import ascii_uppercase
from cStringIO import StringIO

data = os.popen(r"dir %userprofile%\desktop\*.lnk* /s/b").read()
file = open("testitem.txt", "w")
file.write(data)
file.close()


my_data = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase,open("testitem.txt")))


old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

for key, value in my_data.iteritems():
    subprocess.Popen([r"powershell.exe", "$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell" + "\n" +     "$sh.CreateShortcut(\"%s\").TargetPath" % my_data[key].replace("\n", "")], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]


sys.stdout = old_stdout

shared = mystdout.getvalue()
print shared
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me... I think the reason might be somewhere else. You can try `sys.__stdout__.write(shared)` instead of `print shared` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried however still not getting anything. I think nothing is getting captured in the first place. Its strange but after trying numerous things the print is empty no errors just empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing this `sys.stdout = old_stdout` line and add `stdout=sys.stdout` to your main process line for ex like .`Popen(***,stdout=sys.stdout)`